# Cannot open app after short period of time

Tags: xcode, macos

I built a Mac app in Xcode and it works for about a week - 2 weeks and then Mac just says "cannot open app" and I have to rebuild it and drag it into the applications again. I'm using the release profile. Is this because I have no Apple developer profile and I'm using "self-signed"? If so, how do I build something without this self-expiring executable issue? I do not intend to release this to the public and do not want to spend $100/yr for something like this.

Comment: For a Mac app intended to run locally, just don't sign it at all.